# Creating multiple sessions with each new tab with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a new session with each new opened tab. So if I call "chrome.tabs.create" and hit the same url I would like it to create a new session. For example if I hit one page and they use cookies to store my cart when I call "chrome.tabs.create" for a second time it just retrieves my previous session and both tabs are essentially the same thing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [There are analogs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/multi%20login?_category=extensions).

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really, not with an extension.

You can open an incognito tab, but that gives you a second session, you can't open "another" incognito context until you close the first one.

A Chrome App can use [webviews](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) with different partitions to this effect, but cannot really interact with normal browsing.

[Webview is not yet available for extensions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422805) and it's unclear when that will change.

If you need this really badly you can try manipulating cookies with `chrome.cookies` API.

Answer (score 0):

I tested many exteension in Chrome and even the SessionBox seems promising I encouterned some bugs so that I cannot use it easily: I had to recreate my profile everytime regularly.

Afer that I found a chromium fork called [ghostbrowser](https://ghostbrowser.com) which have exactly the feature your need to.

This is a very good alternative as long you are ok with the 4 identities limitation of the Free version.